# Sending file to client Java Play

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I try to send CSV data to the client.

Here's how I proceed :
Client side : ajax call to the server to get the file.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/csv/"+source,
    method:'post',
    data:JSON.stringify(json),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Server side : generate the file then send it back to client.

```
   File file = CSVGenerator.generateFromJson(source, request().body().asJson());
    response().setHeader("Content-Lenght", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+file.toString()+"\"");
    return ok(file).as("text/csv");
```

I tried many returns. for example I tried this:

```
return ok(new FileInputStream(file)).as("text/csv");
```

I also tried many headers like:

```
response().setContent("text/csv");
```

or

```
response().setHeader("Content-Type","text/csv");
```

instead of `.as("text/csv")`

The client get a response with a good header, good data, but never start any download.

What am I missing?

Comment: @EoiFirst You should write the language's name how it's meant to be written. Just like you'd do for a person's name, a brand, or anything else. With that being said, what _does_ happen on the client? The only thing I see that stands out is that `Content-Length` is spelled wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Spelled wrong indeed for length but doesn't change anything. On the client just nothing happen. I can see the response is ok, but no download starts

Comment: What about simply: `return ok(file);`, did you try that?

Comment: I tried indeed. "Same nothing". Do I have to make anything special from the html page to launch the download on response ? Because i just have a <button onclick="exportCSV();">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours more of research, the problem is that the download can't start from an ajax call.

Here's how i solved the problem :

Thanks for the helps :

```
window.open("/csv/"+source+"/"+encodeURIComponent(csvData));
```